# displaying "no results" if input doesn't match array name (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a search function that lets the user search for an item, and if stored, will display a message (inside my results div) if it's in stock or not.

I would like a "no results" message to display until the search finds a result.

I've tried but I'm having trouble. 
If you guys could help, I'd really appreciate it.

Here's my full code:

```js
var user = document.getElementById('user');
var results = document.getElementById('results');

$('#user').keyup(function() {
  search(user.value);
});

var apples = {
  firstName: "apples",
  stock: "in stock"
};

var bananas = {
  firstName: "bananas",
  stock: " not in stock"
};

var contacts = [apples, bananas];

function printPerson(person) {
  results.innerHTML = (person.firstName + " are " + person.stock);
}

function list() {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    printPerson(contacts[i]);
  }
}


function search(match) {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == match) {
      printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="user" placeholder=" type here" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.onkeydown()` in order to output 'no results' as soon as the user enters a string. Once the string has been found in your collection of items the message will be overwritten with your message.

```js
var user = document.getElementById('user');
var results = document.getElementById('results');

$('#user').keydown(function() {
  results.innerHTML = 'no results';
});


$('#user').keyup(function() {
  search(user.value);
});

var apples = {
  firstName: "apples",
  stock: "in stock"
};

var bananas = {
  firstName: "bananas",
  stock: " not in stock"
};

var contacts = [apples, bananas];

function printPerson(person) {
  results.innerHTML = (person.firstName + " are " + person.stock);
}

function list() {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    printPerson(contacts[i]);
  }
}


function search(match) {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == match) {
      printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="user" placeholder=" type here" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

An other would be:

```js
var user = document.getElementById('user');
var results = document.getElementById('results');

$('#user').keyup(function() {
  search(user.value);
});

var apples = {
  firstName: "apples",
  stock: "in stock"
};

var bananas = {
  firstName: "bananas",
  stock: " not in stock"
};

var contacts = [apples, bananas];

function printPerson(person) {
  results.innerHTML = (person.firstName + " are " + person.stock);
}
function printError() {
  results.innerHTML = 'no results';
}
function list() {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    printPerson(contacts[i]);
  }
}


function search(match) {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    console.log(match)
    if (contacts[i].firstName == match) {
      return printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
  }
    return printError(); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="user" placeholder=" type here" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what i needed. i was trying to use if (.firstName != match) to output the error but i was having issue with that.

Comment: it is a valid way, you just need to add an else statement. Look at my answer for the edit.

Comment: i tried to use the else statement but it checks each object name and displays the message. so if i search for apples, it will find apples but it also check bananas - which would display no results even though my search found apples

Comment: i have edited my second snippet. I didn't work because the else statement was in the for loop. Therefore if the first item wasn't matching it would not allow for the for loop to continue on.

Answer (score 3):

I have added searching when a user is typing and stop it when the search is done. This will help you when you will use ajax request which will take time to pull data from server. When no result match then it gives No data. Check out the output.

```js
var user = document.getElementById('user');
var results = document.getElementById('results');

$('#user').keydown(function() {
  results.innerHTML = 'Searching...';
});


$('#user').keyup(function() {
  search(user.value);
});

var apples = {
  firstName: "apples",
  stock: "in stock"
};

var bananas = {
  firstName: "bananas",
  stock: " not in stock"
};

var contacts = [apples, bananas];

function printPerson(person) {
  results.innerHTML = (person.firstName + " are " + person.stock);
}

function list() {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    printPerson(contacts[i]);
  }
}


function search(match) {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;
  var hasAnyMatch = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == match) {
      printPerson(contacts[i]);
      hasAnyMatch = true;
    }
  }

  if(!hasAnyMatch){
    results.innerHTML = 'No data';
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="user" placeholder=" type here" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See below code

```js
var apples = {
  firstName: "apples",
  stock: "in stock"
};
var bananas = {
  firstName: "bananas",
  stock: " not in stock"
};
var contacts = [apples, bananas];
var contactsLength = contacts.length;

function search(key) {

  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == key) {
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = (contacts[i].firstName + " are " + contacts[i].stock);
      break;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "no results";
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user" onkeyup="search(this.value)" placeholder=" type here" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: the code i posted was located in 2 seperate files with jquery loaded. i left it out as i wanted people to focus on my problem.

Comment: above answered solution, is it working fine ??? i think no, try to enter some non-exist work like "abcd" and then erase "bcd" from "abcd" then type "apples"

Comment: i'm so sorry. i ran your code and it showed an error on here but i just checked on my editor and it works great. thankyou.

Comment: you need to add break statement to stop searching, otherwise it would check entire json objects and report "no results" with jquery check here : https://jsfiddle.net/0d9br9u2/

Comment: yeah i added a break and it worked. i feel foolish now :D

Comment: check corner case which i told that first enter "abcd" it should show "no result" then remove "bcd" from "abcd" and then add "apples" above code is also not working for this case.............   above solution also needs **break** statement

Comment: dude. i've said it works. i've fixed it, no need to help any further :)

Comment: Here it is showing error, paste code in your editor, and check it

Comment: here or on an editor will not make any difference. It doesn't work because you haven't a closing <script> tag, that's why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#search-button").click(function () {
    // Before you start the search --

    results.innerHTML =  "no results" ;

    // run your search here
    //then and in the callback function if the search is async

    results.innerHTML =  "x number in stock" ;
});
```

Comment: the error message will display before the user inputs anything

Comment: Only if he runs the code without the user doing anything. The above needs to be put into the function triggered on a button click. I'll make that clear in my code.

Answer (score -1):

function search (match) {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;

```
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {

        if (contacts[i].firstName == match) {
            printPerson(contacts[i]);

        else {cannotSearch ()}
        }
   }
```

}

function cannotSearch ()  {

```
document.Write (
person.firstName + "are " + person.stock);
search ();
```

}

Hope the logic will be useful to you.